# Zend Framework Controller name added twice in link

Tags: zend-framework

Ok so I've been using ZF 1.12 for some time now and it's served my purpose pretty well. Lately I've been noticing some issues. When I follow a link like `href="account"` I would expect it to load the layout and then load the view associated with `AccountContoller->indexAction` in the div containing the `$this->layout()->content` statement.

It does this but then every link contained in the layout now contains this pattern: `baseUrl/account/link`. In other words the current controller "reference" is placed before the link specified in the href tag.

Why is this, and how do I keep it from happening?

Comment: Does it still happen if you put `href="/account" instead?

Comment: using the "/" in front causes it to skip the public folder all together and go right to the url root which is not the desired behavior

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "skip the public folder all together". Nevertheless, you can always use the [Zend View URL Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) to build your URLs instead of using hard-coded ones. Hopefully that'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so for those who would like a more specific solution here is what I did, as per Rolando's advice (thanks again Rolando) instead of hard coding url I used this instead in the layout

`<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'index'));?>`

Comment: Yup, that's the best solution.  You can also use this helper to pass parameters if needed.  ie: url(array('controller'=>'account', 'action'=>'index', 'id'=>'2');

Comment: Glad to help, mark your answer as correct to close the question.